# How to run sonarlint in vscode for typescript in package.json?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, sonarlint

Currently I am using this script - "sonarlint --src 'ui/src/**.tsx'"

But it always says

```
INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
INFO: Standalone mode
WARN: No files to analyze
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 3.418s
INFO: Final Memory: 5M/24M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you give some background about the folder structure? And you also have .tsx files?

Comment: yes, its like this - Project/ui/components/"files".tsx & Project/ui/components/"files".ts

Comment: then try `ui/**/*.tsx`

Comment: tried that; didnt work